# SAS TINV vs EXCEL TINV

Tags: excel, sas

I am planning to convert an Excel code into SAS

There is a function called TINV used in Excel, and the same function is also in SAS with the same syntax, but I am getting two different results for the same  numbers. Please help me know if both are different functions or the same.

SAS:

```
TINV(0.95,2)
```

Result: 2.9199855804

Excel:

```
TINV(0.95,2)
```

Result : 0.070799

Answer (score 2):

Although these functions appear to have the same syntax, they differ in how the arguments are interpreted. It looks as though SAS uses a 1-tailed test, and Excel uses a 2-tailed test, and also SAS follows the convention that probability is defined as 1-p rather than p.

So if in SAS you have `tinv(0.95,2)`, the equivalent excel formula is actually `tinv((1-0.95)*2,2)`.